# Prestashop GET 403 (Forbidden) error for images

Tags: image, permissions, prestashop

Please, can any body help me. I moved my site from one host server to another, and after it my site stops to showing images. I tried to change permissions numbers after it but nothing changed. [Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypFZb.png)

Can Any Body Help Me please.

[One More screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFdKF.png)

Comment: I fix it by my self. Just delete deny from htaccess. :) 

Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it by my self. Just delete deny from htaccess. :) Good Luck

Comment: Can You tell in which htaccess exactly You remove this line?